# Reduce data to boolean values while maintaining unique weeks in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following data

```
year    date        wk  name       type    holiday closed_day
2017    2017-11-27  48  NA          NA      0         0
2017    2017-12-04  49  NA          NA      0         0
2017    2017-12-11  50  NA          NA      0         0
2017    2017-12-18  51  NA          NA      0         0
2017    2017-12-25  52  Christmas   closed  0         1
2017    2017-12-26  52  NA          NA      0         0
2017    2017-12-31  52  NewYearsEve holiday 1         0
```

how do I use dplyr to get

```
year    date        wk  holiday closed_day
2017    2017-11-27  48    0       0
2017    2017-12-04  49    0       0
2017    2017-12-11  50    0       0
2017    2017-12-18  51    0       0
2017    2017-12-25  52    1       1
```

Notice that I don't need name or type just each week and if a holiday or a closed_day occurred in the week (not the sum, just Boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are flexible on which of the `year` and `date` values you get, then you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(wk) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(year, date, holiday, closed_day), funs(max(.)))
# # A tibble: 5 × 5
#      wk  year       date holiday closed_day
#   <int> <int>     <date>   <int>      <int>
# 1    48  2017 2017-11-27       0          0
# 2    49  2017 2017-12-04       0          0
# 3    50  2017 2017-12-11       0          0
# 4    51  2017 2017-12-18       0          0
# 5    52  2017 2017-12-31       1          1
```

Otherwise

```
df %>%
  group_by(wk) %>%
  summarize(year = year[1], date = date[1],
            holiday = 1*any(holiday > 0),
            closed_day = 1*any(closed_day > 0))
# # A tibble: 5 × 5
#      wk  year       date holiday closed_day
#   <int> <int>     <date>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1    48  2017 2017-11-27       0          0
# 2    49  2017 2017-12-04       0          0
# 3    50  2017 2017-12-11       0          0
# 4    51  2017 2017-12-18       0          0
# 5    52  2017 2017-12-25       1          1
```

(I used a slightly different method for `holiday` and `closed_day` the second time, in case you have weeks with "both" and needed just `> 0` logic ... in which case it would be clearer code-wise/data-wise to keep it `logical` instead of numeric.)

Comment: `df%>%group_by(year,wk)%>%summarise_all(max)%>%select(-name,-type)`:-)

Comment: The OP specifically said *"just each week"*, so I'm interpreting that to mean *across years*, so `group_by(year,wk)` is grouping too much. I suggest you do the `select` *before* the `summarize_all`, though ... it doesn't change the return, but with larger datasets it could have an effect.

Comment: This is great. it solved my problem. What is `date = date[1]` doing.

Comment: `summarize` requires each assignment to be length 1. If I do nothing, the field will be dropped. I can't do `date` (as in `transmute`) or `date=date`, because they return a length likely greater than 1. Think of it as one type of summary function; you can do `max`, `mean`, etc, you can also do effectively "first" and "last".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(wk) %>% 
  mutate(holiday = max(holiday) > 0,
         closed_day = max(closed_day) > 0) %>% 
  distinct(wk, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(year, date, wk, holiday, closed_day)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   wk [5]
   year       date    wk holiday closed_day
  <int>     <date> <int>   <lgl>      <lgl>
1  2017 2017-11-27    48   FALSE      FALSE
2  2017 2017-12-04    49   FALSE      FALSE
3  2017 2017-12-11    50   FALSE      FALSE
4  2017 2017-12-18    51   FALSE      FALSE
5  2017 2017-12-25    52    TRUE       TRUE
```

1. Group by `wk`
2. Mutate `holiday` and `closed_day` to logical by asking if the max of each is greater than 0.
3. Return distinct `wk` values
4. Select the variables you want

Comment: No, it drops the `holiday`.

Answer (score 2):

In case a data.table method is also of interest to you, we can do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(date = date[1], holiday = any(holiday), closed = any(closed_day)), 
          by = .(year, wk)]

#    year wk       date holiday closed
# 1: 2017 48 2017-11-27   FALSE  FALSE
# 2: 2017 49 2017-12-04   FALSE  FALSE
# 3: 2017 50 2017-12-11   FALSE  FALSE
# 4: 2017 51 2017-12-18   FALSE  FALSE
# 5: 2017 52 2017-12-25    TRUE   TRUE
```

Note that I summarise the data by year and week, assuming that you would want a separate summary for each week every year.